# Reduction of G-structure on Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, vector-bundles, algebraic-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb C$ and let $V$ be a principal $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ bundle over $X$. Is there a simple criterion for the reduction of structure group to $SO_n(\mathbb C)$ ?